# Spacemacs Evil mode does not have :for?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

I tried to use

> :for num in [1-30]

today in my spacemacs evil mode. But it says
`Unknown command for`

Are `:for` and such command an extension to Vi that is not available for Spacemacs Evil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the for command evaluates in vimscript, which `evil-mode` does not support, because emacs already has its own language, that is elisp. So, instead of using `:for`, you would have to do it in the elisp way, like this:

```
:(cl-loop for i from 1 to 30 do (do-something i))
```

You'll have to learn a little bit of elisp, if you are still not familiarized with it.